# Solution or existence for a second-order semilinear PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, semi-linear-elliptic-pdes

Consider the following PDE:$$0=u_t+u_{yy}+u_{xx}+(x-y)u_y+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u^2+1,$$ with $t \in [0,T], $ and a terminal condition $u_T=-1$ for all $x$ and $y.$ The domain for $x$ and $y$ can be bounded if needed, and the original problem allows to add more boundary conditions on the first derivatives if that can help.

Ideally I would like to find a solution of course, however if I can manage to find an existence / unicity result, even in a weak sense, I would be more than happy. I am open to fixed-point theorems, bootstraps arguments to show regularity ...

It would be highly appreciated if the answer contains a brief explanation, although I'd be satisfied with just the references.

Comment: And the domain contains $y=0$?

Comment: Yes 0 can be in the domain without any issue.

Comment: But does it have to be? If ti doesn't then $y^{-3/2}$ is a nice bounded function, so the problem is very standard, specially because it is the inverse time direction to that of the heat equation. So you could just solve the heat equation (with your nonlinear term which is very nice) with initial data $-1$, call that $v$, and then $u(t)=v(T-t)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No it doesn't. And it is actually better if $0$ is not in the domain of $y$. So the term $y^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ is indeed bounded. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by solving the heat equation with the nonlinear term ? is it in the weak sense ? can you point towards a method ?

Comment: A possible approach to solve such an equation is by a gradient expansion but I do not know if this can help.

Comment: Hi Jon and thank you for your comment. I tried this, maybe that is what you mean by gradient expansion. I first substitute $u\left(t,x,y\right)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}u_{n}\left(x,y\right)\left(T-t\right)^{n}$ and by identifying the powers of $t$ we get the system:

Comment: $$\begin{cases}
u_{0} & =-1\\
u_{1} & =\partial_{yy}u_{0}+\partial_{xx}u_{0}+(x-y)\partial_{y}u_{0}+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u_{0}^{2}+1\\
 & =y^{-\frac{3}{2}}+1\\
u_{2} & =\partial_{yy}u_{1}+\partial_{xx}u_{1}+(x-y)\partial_{y}u_{1}+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u_{1}^{2}+1\\
...
nu_{n}= & \partial_{yy}u_{n-1}+\partial_{xx}u_{n-1}+(x-y)\partial_{y}u_{n-1}+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u_{n-1}^{2}+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{k+m=n}^{+\infty}u_{k}(x,y)u_{m}(x,y)
\end{cases}$$ which gives a polynomial representation of the solution. But that doesn't say it exists right ?

Comment: An existence and unicity argument is more than enough for my problem..

Comment: I meant $\partial_t u_0+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u_0^2+1=0$ at the leading order and the remain as a perturbation. This has an exact solution in terms of a tanh. A good non-trivial starting point. Anyway, for existence you need at least convergence but beyond a perturbation approach it is difficult to see a solution.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not familiar with the method. Could you point me towards a a reference please ?

Comment: This is an approach widely used in fluid mechanics. A good reference for mathematicians is https://books.google.it/books?id=0Iglq1WA5PQC&dq=Marsden+Chorin&source=bl&ots=fh289IdNIu&sig=IW0LsJ7nmLbQU6FaiHD8zkGwDYg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=waleUOqnEoPf4QSbioHACQ&redir_esc=y. See discussion starting from page 38.

Comment: Oh I was more thinking about a reference where this kind of nonlinearity is addressed with your method. Is there a specific chapter in the book I should look into ? I'm not a physicist so reading it might be hard for me.. especially if the chances it works are low.

Comment: Let me say that here the idea is very simple. Formally, insert a small parameter $\epsilon$ on the perturbation part, apply a perturbation series, and set $\epsilon$ to 1 in the end. You will get a non-trivial series but, as I said, this cannot grant existence and could be a too "physicist"-like approach for your taste. The book I cited is for mathematicians anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Jon, I will give it a try, but it could take some time..

Comment: @username Any help would bighly appreciated, as you seem to think the problem is an easy one ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea I was trying to convey in the comments is the following. Let us consider the equation

$$0=u_t+u_{yy}+u_{xx}+(x-y)u_y+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u^2+1.$$

I assume at the leading order the solution of the equation

$$0=u^{(0)}_t+y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u^{(0)2}+1.$$

This has a known exact solution. Then, the next-to-leading order equation can be computed by taking

$$u(t,x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^{(n)}(t,x,y).$$

I assume there could be an ordering parameter such that some kind of convergence exists for the above series. This point is crucial as, being not proven convergence, we cannot claim existence of such a solution. This will give to the next-to-leading order

$$u^{(1)}_t+2y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u^{(0)}u^{(1)}=-u^{(0)}_{yy}-u^{(0)}_{xx}-(x-y)u^{(0)}_y.$$

Note that now the problem is a linear one and one could use Green function techniques to get higher order terms.

Comment: Do you agree that for the higher orders, using your notations, you should have $$u_{t}^{(k)}+2y^{-\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{i+j=k}^{+\infty}u^{(i)}u^{(j)}=u_{yy}^{(k-1)}+u_{xx}^{(k-1)}+(x-y)u_{y}^{(k-1)}.$$ This is somewhat similar to the approach in my comment. You solve for an initial function, and then by iterations solve for the rest. The difficult part is to prove that the series converge. In my case, with power of $T-t$, I can manage when $t$ is very close to $T.$

Comment: You are correct. Yes, proof of convergence could be complicated.

Comment: Using your method, we have 
$$u_{0}\left(t,x,y\right)=y^{3/4}\tanh\left(arctanh\left(-\alpha y^{-3/4}\right)-y^{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(t-T\right)\right)$$ 
and then for every $k>0$ that 

$$\partial_{t}u_{k}+2y^{-\frac{3}{2}}u_{0}u_{k}=-\partial_{yy}u_{k-1}-\partial_{xx}u_{k-1}-(x-y)\partial_{y}u_{k-1}-\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
i+j=k\\
i,j<k
\end{array}}^{+\infty}u_{i}u_{j}=f_{k}(t,x,y)$$ 

giving the simple solution $$u_{k}\left(t,x,y\right)=-\int_{t}^{T}f_{k}(s,x,y)\exp\left(\int_{t}^{s}y^{-3/2}u_{0}(u,x,y)du\right)ds.$$

Comment: My question is now that we know how to write the series, how one proves convergence ? And even upon succeeding, how one can say that this proves existence of a solution ?
Fyi, a simple implicit scheme without a lot of efforts gives a nice smooth looking solution for this.

Comment: In principle, you are proving existence by construction but without convergence this is not possible.  I have in mind something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem.

Comment: This works for ODEs pretty nicely. For PDEs and especially non-linear, you have to work much more and consider sobolov spaces and compact operators, or consider viscosity solutions.. Is there a link between your approach and pde theory?

Comment: This is just an application of perturbation theory around a given leading order solution and so, there is no particular reference I can give.